# Copy data from phone to wifi network

Tags: wi-fi, networking, file-transfer

USB port on my phone broke (can't transfer data). My phone uses built-in memory, no memory card.

It works, I connect to wifi, etc. Is there any software or easy way to copy all my files from phone to network? Mostly I need to get pictures and videos out. Using email will be tooo slow.

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.vmad.com/index-3_droidcopy.html) and from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmad.droidcopy.server) And yes, I am affiliated with the company in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an app such as [WiFi Tiles transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer). All you have to do is to download the app and clicking the `start` button. Then you can go to the server page you're given (on the app screen) and you can access all the files and folders of your phone memory.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the WiFi network. Install Dropbox/Google drive or any other similar service on your computer. Install the app for the same service on your phone. And then go into your favorite photo browser/gallery and send the files over to the service and then you will have them automatically on your computer(if you have installed the applications).

This also gives you a backup of the photos and videos.

**Simple steps one by one, with my recommended service:**

1. Connect to WiFi with your cellphone
2. If you dont have a Google account, make one here: [Google Signup](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&ltmpl=default).
   Most likely you have a google account, when you have an Android phone. Otherwise, you can not download apps through the Google Play.
3. Install "Google Drive" on your computer. You can download it from [the google drive download page](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive).
4. Install "Google Drive" on your phone. Download it from the [Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs).
5. Go into your favorite photo browser or gallery app on your phone. You can then select all files or only the ones you wanna transfer, and choose the "share"([image: Share button]) button and choose "Google Drive". It will then use some time depending on the internet connection you have.
6. You can then go on your computer and find the files inside the "Google Drive" folder.

Your files is now safely saved/backed up on three devices. Your computer, phone and "Google Drive".

I hope this solution works for you.

You can also make a permanent solution by downloading and using [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full&hl=no) wich will automatically upload photos to Google Drive when you take photos or videos.