# How can I access my photos/videos from my HTC Sensation XL default on 'charge only' and with unresponsive touch screen?

Tags: screen, data-recovery, photos

My HTC was dropped in water and now has unresponsive touch screen. The screen is not the problem, as I've replaced it and it still have the same problem. I can't send it off for repairs because it will be factory resetted. This phone has 2 years worth of important photos and videos, hence I really need to access the phone. I don't mind about the phone, it just have a lot of sentimental value. So can anyone help me with this?

- The phone is recognised when connected to computer
- Android 4
- Can see the screen, but not responsive to touch
- Default on 'charge only' upon connecting to computer

Comment: Is *USB debugging* enabled?

Comment: USB debugging is not enabled, I'm afraid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an app like WiFi File Transfer as explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49308/23379). You can use a [USB OTG](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-on-the-go/info) cable and connect a mouse to use your phone for your data recovery process.

You may have to hurry as the water that is already inside the device can harm the hardware in your device. Keep the device turned off and remove battery. Try to give it a little bit of sunlight. *do not expose it to direct **strong** sunlight*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sid, but I cannot use the screen at all. It simply does not respond to touch; I cannot download any apps. Yes, may be my fault because I put it straight in my conservatory (30+ degrees Celcius). There must be a way of accessing my data with nowadays technology - hence I've resorted to you Android Enthusiasts!

Comment: Did you read the part **You can use a USB OTG cable and connet a mouse to use your phone for your data recovery process.** ?

Comment: "Adding sunlight" might not be the best idea for a water-damaged device. Rather put it in a back together with rice (which draws out the water). Those "salt-bags" found with many leather things one buys might even be a little faster. Leave it for at least 24h (better 3 days).

Comment: @Izzy Well, I also have heard about rice, Was not not sure whether it's true or not. Good to know.

Comment: @Sid I never tried it myself (I mean, to dip my device in water), so I had no chance to confirm (which is why I added the "salt-bags" thingy). But I read it quite a lot on the net, not only on blogs, but also in forum discussions. Didn't look like fake to me. And as rice (and even more salt) draws water, it sounds convincing: Put rice and water into a pot, close it (to rule out vaporization), and see for yourself what happens :)

Comment: @Izzy Good idea!! Shall I add some salt as well? :D :D

Comment: @Sid Yeah, but no peppers or curcuma, as they have the side-effect of making your cover looking different (either reddish or yellowish) #D // Honestly: You know what kind of "salt bags" I was referring to I hope? Those little rectangle pads, mostly in white, which shops/manufacturers put into e.g. leather bags to keep them dry?

Comment: Wow! Haven't thought about connecting a mouse! Part ordered and I'll let you know if it works by Tuesday! Thanks a for the input, Sid and Izzy :)

Comment: @Izzy, Err.. you mean [Silica gel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silica_gel) packets like [these](http://image.made-in-china.com/2f0j00sBJafiRKYUgH/Silica-Gel-Desiccant-In-OPP-Bag-Cobalt-Chloride-Free-Dmf-Free.jpg)?

Comment: Looks like the ones I had in mind, yes – and the Wikipedia description fits. Only difference is the pic looks like "plastic bags", and the ones I saw up to now rather used some kind of paper or cotton.